# detect card symbol using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to detect the difference between a spade, club, diamond and heart. the number on the card is irrelevant, just the suit matters.

i've tried color detection by looking at just the red or black colors, but that still leaves me with two results per color. how could i make sure i can detect each symbol individually?

for instance: i have a picture of a red hart, a red diamond, a black spade and a black club. i want to draw the contours of each symbol in a different color.

I'm using my webcam as a camera.

Answer (score 1):

As the card symbol is at fixed positions, you may try below (e.g. in `OpenCV 3.2` `Python`):

1. Crop the symbol at top left corner, `image = image[h1:h2,w1:w2]`
2. Threshold the symbol colors to black, the rest to white, `thresh = mask = cv2.inRange(image,(0,0,0),(100,100,100))`
3. Perform a find contour detection, `_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours()`
4. Get the area size of the contour. `area = cv2.contourArea(contour)`
5. Compare the area to determine which one of the 4 symbols it belongs to.

In which you have to build the area thresholds of each symbol for step 4 to compare. All the `cv2` functions above are just for reference.

Hope this help.

Comment: sorry for this late response, but no it does not. i need to be able to detect them real time at different distances, so contourArea wont work for me

Comment: @user3499284 I see. Then, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: i haven't found a solution yet, i've tried haar cascades, template matching,  color detection (which doesnt work cus there are two symbols per color). i've tried to detect the object based on edges aswell, which only works for the red diamond

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have major perspective distortion (when it may work anyway), [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) is very effective. You can run this in red and black channels separately (obviously don't look for red spades etc.).

Take a look at e.g. (not mine)

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv

For playing cards, see also https://github.com/arnabdotorg/Playing-Card-Recognition

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way today, I have a better idea :)

Answer (score 0):

If the suit of your cards is always identical (only one single kind of card) you could just store images of spade, club, diamond and hart and then check the cross-correlation of the given image to your references and pick the highest value (see [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28322/python-normalized-cross-correlation-to-measure-similarites-in-2-images)). If you have a fairly large sample set of different kinds of cards that have slight differences between the suit-representations you can pretty much follow [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_svm/py_svm_opencv/py_svm_opencv.html#svm-opencv) almost exactly to do a four-way classification of your training set and use a svm, clustering or other approaches, which are available in open-cv.

hope this helps and all the best

Comment: well i basicly have a symbol of a hart, spade, club and diamond i need to be able to indentify, no real playing cards are used

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code, so can't really tweak what you have, but more generally you ought to be able to train it just the same except for the symbol instead of color:

Here is a sample code for doing a specific card. You can either train them to be card specific, thus capturing all of the symbols by specific card, or back it up and more generally train for the symbol (heart / diamond). You should also look at [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) on opencv.

There are a couple guides and [code already completed](https://github.com/elnormous/carddetection) for this on github.

[Here is a tutorial worth reading](https://rdmilligan.wordpress.com/2014/07/05/playing-card-detection-using-opencv/)

Comment: did you forget to include the sample code for doing a specific card, or is it on the github page?